# Computed property based on presence of non-required properties

Tags: edgedb

We know we can create a computed property based on other properties like so as per the [docs](https://www.edgedb.com/docs/datamodel/computeds#computeds),

```
type Person {
  property first_name -> str;
  property last_name -> str;
  property full_name := .first_name ++ ' ' ++ .last_name;
}
```

I'd like to create a computed property that shows whether a given combination of non-required properties are all present or all absent, conceptually like this,

```
type Person {
  property first_name -> str;
  property last_name -> str;
  property has_name := .first_name is not null and .last_name is not null;
}
```

However, EdgeDB does not have a concept of null so this does not work. Is it possible to accomplish this? If so, could the resulting computed property itself be `required`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check optional properties for emptiness using the [exists](https://www.edgedb.com/docs/stdlib/set#operator::exists) operator:

```
type Person {
  property first_name -> str;
  property last_name -> str;
  property has_name := exists .first_name and exists .last_name;
}
```